# Bootstrap affix attribute to have a fixed nav below a header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a page with a header, and a navigation below that's fixed when you scroll to a certain point.

I'm trying to use the built in 'affix' plugin but I'm struggling a little. I've fixed a couple problems with the navigation not sitting in the same place which was adding these lines..

```
.navbar.affix {
top:0px;
width:100%;
z-index:11;}
```

However, when it fixes it to the top, the page jumps up and therefore it's not a smooth transition. I understand why, I think, because the space where the navigation was is now not being used, so the rest of the content shifts up..

What do I need to do so that when the navigation gets fixed, the content doesn't shift up?

Thanks in advance.

Demo - http://samtodd.co.uk/header-navigation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a javascript solution:

```
$('.navbar[data-spy="affix"]').on('affix.bs.affix', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $fix = $('<div class="affix-height-fix">').height($this.outerHeight(true));
    $this.after($fix);
}).on('affix-top.bs.affix', function () {
    $(this).next('.affix-height-fix').remove();
});
```

Basically it adds a new element with the same height as the navbar when it gets fixed at the top of the page so the rest of the elements don't shift up. The added element is removed when the navbar resets its position.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It seems to work fine, however it does seem to cause the scroll not to work properly after the nav is fixed.

http://jsfiddle.net/Sambolina/wLD9c/

Comment: @Sambolina Can you describe the issue with the scroll? I didn't notice anything strange in the fiddle

Comment: Sorry, I was originally looking at it on Chrome, and basically the scroll bar on the right will lock at the top, even when scrolling. Just tried it on Firefox and Safari and it works fine though.

Comment: Just uploaded it to the original demo site and the scroll issue isn't there, even on Chrome. Thanks for the help!!